Should I prefer using basic_istream::tellg() or filesystem::file_size()?
Suppose I have a std::filesystem::path, which I then open as an std::ifstream, and suppose that I want to determine its size (e.g. maybe I want to read the whole file).
Should I prefer calling
auto file_size = std::filesyste::file_size(my_path);

or rather, after opening it, calling
my_fstream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
auto file_size my_stream.tellg();

?
Relevant considerations (thanks commenters):

Execution speed (perhaps depending on file size? ... I'm thinking of the tape metaphor; if seeking to the end really means rolling the tape, then...)
Susceptibility to race conditions
Veracity (what is "more true"? What can I rely on when reading from the file?)


Prefer std::filesystem::file_size(). It will always report the correct number (the answer you get from fstream depends on how you open it) and it uses the underlying OS functionality to get the value, which is much better than trying to seek around a file.

Having said that, there are of course caveats. The actual content of the file may not match the file size. On modern systems this isn’t so much an issue. If you just want to read an entire file, slurp it up with the stream functionality.

I've seen an argument I kind of agree with that file_size is racy.  The file could be swaped or changed between your call to the file_size and the actual opening and "locking" of the file.  tellg() doesn't have that issue since the file is already open.

Opening a file does not lock it.

@NathanOliver the file could still be modified by someone else after you open it, unless you use permissions to prevent that (which the stream API does not allow, but OS APIs may)

This is more of an opinion, but I generally prefer working with the actual file handle if I have one already -- so, I'd use the tellg version.
This eliminates problems where the path changes while you have the handle open. Unix-ish systems can still modify the file while you're reading it, but there isn't much you can do there.

"Unix-ish systems can still modify the file while you're reading it" - Windows systems can do that, too.

You should think why you need a file size at all. Do you want to estimate how much time your processing will take? Do you want to do sanity checking and warn the user that the file looks wrong? You don't need the "absolutely correct" number for these purposes. I can't imagine any situation where "more correct" is significantly better than "less correct".
If you want to consider other aspects: std::filesystem::file_size(my_path) should be faster, but less compatible (c++17). ifstream is inconvenient because it requires two statements, but not so much if your code reads the file right afterwards.
Regardless of race conditions, you can't guarantee that you have any particular number of bytes to read until you actually read them.

"should be faster" - are you certain that's the case? For any file size?

No, not certain. Never tried it, so can't say for sure.

Asking the filesystem for its existing metadata is likely to be faster than opening the file, seeking it, and querying it

@RemyLebeau: But I'm going to open the file anyway...

@einpoklum there are ways to read in the file without having to know its size up front.

@RemyLebeau: Yes, but I need it for reasons.

@einpoklum and if you can't tell us those reasons, we can't be very helpful.  Honestly if you're going to read the file anyway, just read it and count the number of bytes you read.
